# Swift - ¿Como trabajar con imagen vectorial en juegos?

Tags: swift2, iphone

Baje una imagen vectorial en pdf de 36x36 pixeles, a la cual cuando hago zoom no se pixela. Esta imagen la agregue al proyecto en la carpeta "Assets.xcassets" y en "Scale Factors" elegí "Single Vector".

Pero sucede que la agregue a mi aplicación (un juego que estoy haciendo) de esta forma:

```
news = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "News")
news.setScale(7.6)
news.position = CGPoint(
    x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
    y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) - 20
)
self.addChild(news)
```

Y cuando ejecuto la aplicación en mi iPhone, la imagen aparece pixelada.

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer para que mi imagen no se pixele?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has de tener en cuenta que `Xcode` no utiliza la imagen vectorial para usarla directamente. Cuando añades una imagen en formato `PDF` lo que hace `Xcode` al compilar es crear todos los `assets` `@1x`, `@2x` y `@3x` en función de las plataformas donde se va utilizar. Por tanto, importar un `PDF` lo único que hará es facilitar la gestión de las imágenes en `Xcode`.

Para que no se vea pixelado has de importar un `PDF` del tamaño que se vaya a mostrar. Por ejemplo, si en `Interface Builder` pongo una imagen de 40x40 (esto sería `@1x`) tengo que importar una imagen en PDF de 40x40 para que Xcode genere las versiones 80x80 (`@2x`) y 120x120 (`@3x`) sin pixelado.

Para trabajar directamente con imágenes vectoriales puedes utilizar librerías como [SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit) o [SVGQuartzRenderer](https://github.com/splashdust/SVGQuartzRenderer) aunque hay que tener en cuenta que no implementan el 100% del estándar SVG. Por otro lado, si buscas un poco probablemente haya alguna librería más.